# Using () OVER or HAVING clause to get monthly aggregates of counts

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have a big dataset on ticket sales throughout a single year. The schema I am working with is:

```
ID
date_time_sale (Timestamp, yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss)
weekday (varchar, Mon to Sun)
number_tickets (integer)   
ticket_price (float)
total_price (float)
```

I am trying to get to get the weekday of every month of the year where the highest number of tickets was sold, so, for example, the output would be:

| year | month | weekday | total_tickets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2015 | 01 | SAT | 5400 |
| 2015 | 02 | SUN | 4300 |
| 2015 | 03 | SUN | 6400 |

I tried using the following, but admittedly SQL is not my strongest skill:

```
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time_sale) AS YEAR,
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time_sale) AS MONTH,
      week_day,
      RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, MOMTH ORDER BY count(week_day) ASC) weekday_count
      from ticket_sales
      order by YEAR, MONTH
```

But I keep running into errors. I tried using a HAVING clause, but I coludn't go anywhere. Any tip on how to effectively use the RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY) clause to get this output, please? Or do I need to use COUNT () OVER?

The analysis exception says:

```
`cannot resolve '`YEAR`' given input columns: [ticket_sales.YEAR, ticket_sales.MONTH, weekday]; line 1 pos 292;\n'Sort ['YEAR ASC NULLS FIRST, 'MONTH ASC NULLS FIRST], true\n+- Project [YEAR#342, MONTH#358
```

but then it is quite a long error.

Update:

So I tried this code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year,
          month,
          week_day,
          COUNT (week_day) OVER (PARTITION BY year, month, week_day) AS weekday_count 
          from ticket_sales
           order by year, month, weekday_count DESC
```

And what that did is give the results of all week days in the for every months, so the output is 12*7 instead of 12 rows. Still ways to learn around this but at least I am somewhere.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: The database has been provided externally by my lecturer.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your questin and add the error(s) you get

Answer (score 0):

Try this query and let me know if return the desire result:

I'm not sure if field name is number_tickets or total_tickets, I used number_tickets.

First I sum numbers tickets from year, month and week day, then return a row per year and month with the week's day in which more tickets were sold.

```
WITH total_by_day AS (SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM date_time_sale) AS YEAR,
      EXTRACT(MONTH FROM date_time_sale) AS MONTH,
      week_day,
      SUM(number_tickets) AS number_tickets
FROM ticket_sales
GROUP BY YEAR, MONTH, week_day)

SELECT DISTINCT 
      YEAR,
      MONTH,
      FIRST_VALUE(week_day) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY number_tickets DESC) AS week_day,
      FIRST_VALUE(number_tickets) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, MONTH ORDER BY number_tickets DESC) AS total_tickets
FROM total_by_day
ORDER BY YEAR, MONTH;
```

In Postgresql database I got the desire result.

Comment: So, that didn't work, but I got somewhere.

Comment: I changed it recently. Check it again. Now I sum all tickets sold by year, month and week day first.

Comment: So, what I did was first of all break my date and time into separate columns, and then my code was the following:

<pre> <code> SELECT DISTINCT YEAR, MONTH,
<pre> <code>      week_day,
<pre> <code>      COUNT (week_day) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR, MONTH, week_day) <pre> <code>      AS weekday_count
<pre> <code>      from ticket_sales
<pre> <code>      order by YEAR, MONTH

What that gave me is all the table but showing the total sales for all the days, instead of just the max, so, for January, it showed me all saturday, sunday, etc sales.

I still need to just get the maximum, though.

Comment: Check my query again, it should return a table like your desire output.

Comment: Sorry for that, I thought codes can show in comments. I posted an update up there. I will try your query.

Comment: It's ok. You should put the code into \`\` in comments. I think you don't need a count.

Comment: Nope, sorry, that didn't work. But yeah, I will wake up tomorrow with a fresher mind and think about this. Thanks for all your help! :)

Comment: Ok, you are welcome! Could you tell me what is returning my query? Why it is wrong? Maybe I will be able to fix it.

Comment: Just a long error. I am also working of spark.sql, so, that's another thing I am embedding into.

Comment: I am not familiar with spark.sql. The sql syntax and functions depends of the database used. You can take the idea of my query and replace the functions that are not available in your database. If I can help you on something let me know.